# Rsyncing VPS's "/" directory to an external drive: Good backup solution?

Tags: debian, backup, vps, rsync

I have a VPS with Debian 6 (squeeze) and want to back it up on an external drive at home, so that in case of failure I can restore the complete operating system with all software, settings and databases.

The solution I think of is to `rsync` the server's `/` directory to the external drive, like `rsync --one-file-system --archive "root@server.address:/" "/media/backup"`. The `--one-file-system` option will exclude virtual directories like `/proc`, `/sys`, `/dev` and `/run`.

Most VPS providers don't have the option of booting the server from a virtual CD or modifying its filesystem when it's not running, so backup restoration to a new VPS would have to involve a fresh install of Debian modifying itself.

I think it can be done by `rsync`ing the external drive to the server's `/` directory, with a command like `rsync --one-file-system --archive --delete "/media/backup" "root@new.server.address:/"`. `--delete` is used to delete files on the server that are not in the backup, and `--one-file-system` not to delete virtual directories (that were excluded when making the backup).

The virtualization platform is OpenVZ, so the kernel is shared and `/boot` is empty.

Is the described solution reliable? Should I exclude some more directories? If the solution is not reliable, what alternative do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the described solution reliable?

The only thing you need to be careful of is ensuring critical files are not being written to or otherwise in heavy use when you make the `rsync`. Other than that, this method will work fine. It's reliable in this sense because Linux has no concept of a registry or global key/value data-store.

One thing you might want to do is disable uid/gid matching (`--numeric-ids`), otherwise if your destination system has a user with the same user/groups (e.g. `nobody` or `mailman`) then `rsync` will swap the UID, and may/may not swap it back depending on what order you restore the files (e.g. if `/etc/passwd` is present with the mappings or not).

> Should I exclude some more directories?

I don't feel this is necessary. I've used `-auvz` when making `rsync`s and never had an issue with them. You might want to use `rsnapshot`, it'll give you `rsync`s plus rotational backups at little additional cost.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Hot Copy](http://www.r1soft.com/tools/linux-hot-copy/) for snapshotting functionality without LVM. It requires loading a kernel module, though. So using it in an OpenVZ environment likely would not be an option unless the provider has loaded it for you.